# How can I save changed file within this module?

Tags: python-3.x, database, dbf

I have a DBF file(~2thousands string). My goal is change some values in raws for correct values.
https://dbfread.readthedocs.io 
I use this module.
But I can't figure out, how to save changed text? Or maybe this moudle is just for reading dbf files?

Standart file method .close - doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Each record must be saved individually, and this can be done in two ways:

```
dbf.write(record, {'cust_name': 'new data', 'cust_rate': 0.09)
```

and

```
with record:
    record.cust_name = 'new data'
    record.cust_rate = 0.09
# context manager ends, record is automatically saved
# more code here
```

Unlike modern databases, each record in `dbf` is a live copy.  I used to have changes written to disk immediately, but then a record could become corrupted if a later field change errored out.  So now changes are queued and only written to disk with a `.write()` command, or when the record's context manager is successfully exited.